# WPF FlowDocument printing only to small area

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, flowdocument

I am printing plain text in WPF by using a FlowDocument, FlowDocumentPaginator and PrintDialog. My approach is based on [this article](http://someblokeontheinternet.blogspot.com.mt/2009/11/printing-contents-of-text-box-or-just.html) and is implemented as follows:

```
        var printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            var flowDocument = new FlowDocument();

            var paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Courier New");
            paragraph.FontSize = 10;
            paragraph.Margin = new Thickness(0);
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(this.textToPrint));

            flowDocument.FontSize = 10;
            flowDocument.Blocks.Add(paragraph);

            var paginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource)flowDocument).DocumentPaginator;
            printDialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Chit");
        }
```

This works good for printing stuff with narrow width. But when I try to print a long string, it all gets stuffed in a small area:

[image]

I checked dimensions in the print dialog's `PrintTicket` and in the paginator, and they seem to be okay:

[image]

So, what is causing this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I am not at work but I can tell you it is creating two columns.  Make a long document and you will see it.  You need to tell the flowdocument it is one column and tell the flowdocument the width of the printer.

Comment: Good observation. Could you expand on how to implement your suggestions in an answer, at your convenience please? [Edit: I see you already did. Thanks.]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is some code I use

```
flowDocument.PagePadding = new Thickness(standardThickness);
flowDocument.ColumnGap = 0;
flowDocument.ColumnWidth = printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth;
```

You need to tell the flowdocument it is one column and tell the flowdocument the width of the printer.

Comment: Perfect, this worked. I just suggest you add what you wrote in the comment (the two column thing) in your answer so that can people can find all the relevant information in it.